# How to get the "well, this is embarrassing" screen every time I start Firefox

Tags: firefox, restore, session, session-manager

Sometimes, when Firefox doesn't quit cleanly (perhaps because it crashed, or because the whole computer crashed or didn't successfully terminated Firefox when shutting down), Firefox shows a **Well, this is embarrassing** page where you can manually select the tabs you want to restore.

I *really* like this feature, and I'd like to see that screen every time I start Firefox. I have a tendency of not closing tabs, and with this screen, I can choose which tabs I really want.

Is there a way (an extension I suppose) to get this message each time (other than manually crashing Firefox each time I want to quit it)?

Comment: Here How to get the “well, this is embarrassing” screen every time you start Firefox
http://blog.dt.in.th/2011/02/firefox-sessionrestore/

Comment: Why don't you make this as an answer. I'll try it right away, and hope it will be the validated answer.

Comment: The problem is that on GNU/Linux, I don't have such a file, it must be included in a .jar. And I would need root access.

Answer (score 3):

You can display the session restore "well, this is embarrassing" page at any time once Firefox is running (and quite possibly all your tabs are already open!) by typing `about:sessionrestore` in the address bar. Can you do this if you have selected "Show a blank page" for the "When Firefox starts" option as Pierre suggests? Worth a try.

Can you make `about:sessionrestore` your "home page" and display your "home page" when Firefox starts?!

More information:

- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Session_Restore
- https://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Session+Restore

Comment: I already tried that, but the list of tabs to restore is then empty

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I'm getting well what your need is, but there is a preference that you can set to re-open Firefox with the tabs opened like they were when you've closed Firefox the last time you used it:

[image]

Comment: No, he's looking to have the "Which of the former tabs do you want me to open?" screen on restart, which is not an option here.

Comment: Ok. But he is not far from there.. He just has to close the opened tabs he doesn't want anymore. It's a reverse selection, and the websites are "reached" before he can choose the one he wants to keep. But it's way better than to have to crash an app ;°)

Answer (score 1):

This can be a problem with the file `sessionstore.js` and `sessionstore.bak` in the Profile Folder.

Delete `sessionstore.js` and `sessionstore.bak` in the Profile 
Folder. If you see files `sessionstore-##.js` with a number in the left part of the name like `sessionstore-1.js` then delete those as well.